# How to schedule (and reset) a task programmatically with SpringFramwork?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, timer, quartz-scheduler, spring-annotations

There is a situation where I want to invoke a method after some predetermined time, say 30 sec or 5 min.

Time needs to be configured at run time, means I should be able to change time dynamically from 5 min to 3 min.(reset the timer to new interval programmatically)

I am developing a dynamic web project using Spring framework.

I have checked the Quartz and Timer classes but they seem to read XML configuration for parameters such as delay, repeatInterval and so on.

How can I do that? Does Spring provide any support for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is to configure and inject an instance of something that implements Spring's `TaskScheduler` interface (e.g. `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`). This provides various methods to schedule tasks for delayed execution.

Quartz is overkill for this.

Comment: can you give any reference link so that I can understand more? As I am new to this and not so familiar with these stuff, kindly excuse me for silly questions.

Comment: @Sagar: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler