# Running scheduled method with lazy-init option of the class it belongs to

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, lazy-initialization

I have a class 'ABC' which gets initialized lazily at the time of context-up depending on some external parameters. Class has one method 'test' with `@Scheduled` annotation which does some scheduled activity.

```
public class ABC{
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=100000)
    public void test(){
    }
}
```

XML file is like this:

```
<bean id="abc" class="com.test.ABC" lazy-init="true" />
```

Irrespective of whether I initialize the class or not, @Scheduled method is always called.

Is there any way to run @Scheduled method only when class is initialized?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a `@PostConstruct` method to intialize a programmatic timer.
And then use this programmatic timer instead of `@Schedule`.

@See skaffman`s answer on this [question about programmatic timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613145/267197).